# Cannot run program "npx": error=2, No such file or directory when running React Native app

Tags: react-native, npx

I have been working with `react-native` project in another pc and it has been working correctly. Now I cloned project to another device where I have `react-native` installed since I work with other project and I cannot run it.

When I run `react-native run-android` I get this error:

**Cannot run program "npx": error=2, No such file or directory**

Comment: What npm version are you using? `npm -v`

Comment: If you use Ubuntu or Mac OS, please run Android Studio with below command on Terminal.
`
$ open -a "Android Studio.app"
`
After that, build your react-native android app on the Android Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple steps you need to go through to make it work with `npx`

- `sudo npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`
- `sudo npm i -g npx`
- `npx react-native run-android`

---

More detailed explanation why this is happenig

Issue was that Facebook is not using anymore `react-native-cli` as they are using `npx`.

As stated in [Facebook page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started):

> If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues.

So i had to run `sudo npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` to remove `react-native-cli`

They also say that `npx` is shipped with `nodejs` but that wasn't my case.

> React Native has a built-in command line interface, which you can use to generate a new project. You can access it without installing anything globally using npx, which ships with Node.js.

So I had to install it using `sudo npm i -g npx`

After installing `npx` then just need to run `npx react-native run-android`.

Be aware of **`npx`** before `react-native run-android`

Now you don't have any command `react-native` now we only have 'npx' and `react-native run-android` is just a parameter for `npx`. For ex. to start metro we should run `npx react-native start`

Answer (score 9):

I'm using Android Studio 4 on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.6.
I solved the problem by running Android Studio with bellow command on console.

```
$ open -a "Android Studio.app"
```

Comment: It would be great to know why this helps, but it helps all the same. Thank you

Comment: since I am pretty sure you have your .env variables in your terminal profile that is pointing to android

Comment: open -a /Applications/Android\ Studio.app

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues, so I followed these steps:

1. Start by installing the latest version of Android Studio (Don't delete the old version, just copy paste that to another directory or in my case I just added the Android Studio 3.2.1 that I had to a folder called `olderAndroidStudio`, on mac).
2. Make sure you `don't` click on import settings from Existing.
3. Follow along the installation, and complete it.
4. Build and Run, app runs without any problems.

I additionally uninstalled react-native-cli using the method given in the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, this worked for me, I just update my android studio and then restart android studio!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just quit Android Studio and reopened, and the error was gone.

Maybe throw in a `./gradlew clean` for goo measure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by finding the command that was throwing error and ran it directly

```
node -e "console.log(require('react-native/cli').bin)"
```

which outputs a path, something like

```
$HOME/my-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js
```

then I pasted that path in **android/app/build.gradle**

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    cliPath: "$HOME/my-app/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/bin.js" // <--- add this
]
```